# How do I extract everything from the nth line in cell? (using regextract in sheets)

Tags: regex, google-sheets, spreadsheet

My goal is to return all the lines after the 4th line (in some cells I might have 2 more lines, in others 3 or more). I could use `(\n.*){4}` and an isna function, but in some cells I might have a 5th or more lines that I want to extract (without it returning an error in case there isn't a 4th or 5th line in the cell at all). I've tried inserting the `$` so it can take everything from the end of the string, but don't know quite how to position it. [see example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LevPQ.png)

Comment: I want to extract any line from the 4th one down (regardless of how many); but I won't add any other text strings / replace to them as I did in the case of lines 2 through 4. I've used this one that returns just the last line REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"(\n.+$)"), but nothing else  from the 4th line on. Does that make sense?

Comment: Please copy and paste code into your question as text rather than using screenshots of code.   As it stands, if anybody want to help you with your example they will need to type the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A,"^(?:.*\n){4}((?:.*\n?)+)"),""))
```

The expression `^(?:.*\n){4}((?:.*\n?)+` matches:

- `^` - Start line anchor.
- `(?:.*\n){4}` - 0+ characters other than newline followed by a newline exactly 4 times.
- `((?:.*\n?)+` - A capture group that holds any remaining lines following the same pattern but an optional newline character.

Since it's a capture group, `REGEXEXTRACT()` will return the substring captured in this group or an error if empty; hence the `IFERROR()`.